# how to calculate time when the object is not moving at a constant speed

Tags: logic

suppose a car is moving at speed of 100 kms per hour and after each hour the speed of the car gets increased by 50 kms so from second hour speed is 150 kms/hr and at third hour speed is 200 kms/hr and so on. so to cover a distance of 4000 kms how much time would the car need? i am looking for a formula for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $\frac {146} {13}$ hours.

Try to see that at $11$th hour the car will cover $3850$ kms. In the $12$th hour the speed of the car is $100 + (12-1)50 = 650$ kms/hr. So in the next $\frac {150} {650} = \frac {3} {13}$ hours the car will reach the destination.So the total amount of time required for the car to reach the destination is $11 \frac {3} {13} = \frac {146} {13}$ hours.

Comment: i agree with the answer and i was also able to do it it cumulative form like adding 100+150+200 and so on and reach at 3850 but is there any formula for doing this calculation? what if the distance hypothetically was 400,000 kms then adding speed at each hour manually would be tire some so is there any formula for it? if yes please share. and thanks for the answer.

Comment: To see how many complete hours the car will have to go to reach a destination of distance $a$ (say) you only have calculate the $\left \lfloor n \right \rfloor$ where $n$ is the positive root of the equation $\frac {x} {2} (200 + 50(x-1)) =a.$